# Is noun verbing becoming more prevalent?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, slang

My subjective experience is that noun verbing - that is, turning a noun into a verb - is becoming more common. For example, one can say "beer me" to ask someone to give me a beer, using "beer" as a noun. Or recently a friend told me they were "pajamaing around", as in, walking around in their pajamas. Both of these forms sound natural and easily make sense to my native ears.

I first recognized the concept of verbing nouns many years ago and it seems like it's more common/accepted now than before. However I have no objective evidence to back this up. Is this phenomenon indeed becoming more common/prevalent, particularly in North American English?

Comment: I doubt it  since over 400 years ago the Bard was Shakespearing lots of words. Although  of course, there was back then hardly anyone speaking North American English. You might have to be more explicit about  the start and end dates of the phenomenon ("before" is vague and I, for one, don't know how long you've been using English).

Comment: You will never speak good English unless you have a love affair with the language. And people who use the sorts of expressions you describe, murder the spoken and written word. It is the equivalent of a poor dress sense or walking around with body odour - no law against it but it will not open doors for you.

Comment: @Clare: All this [beforing and aftering](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22beforing+and+aftering%22) just makes me think we're too obsessed with turning *nouns* into *verbs*, and ignoring all the good work done by ***gerunds***. They pioneered the idea of turning *verbs* into *nouns,* paving the way for my cited source to carry the torch further and turn ***prepositions*** into nouns. Actually, thinking of things like [*toing and froing*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/toing-and-froing), I reckon the bottom line is ***T'was ever thus***.

Comment: I've got to think a huge number of words evolved this way.  Like looking up the definition of "hammer" the theory is that it evolved like> Old English hamor, hamer, of Germanic origin: related to Dutch hamer, German Hammer, and Old Norse hamarr ‘rock.’ **The original sense was probably ‘stone tool.’** https://www.google.com/search?q=hammer&oq=hammer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=hammer+definition

Comment: oh, and my point is , that hammering on something (using hammer as a verb) isn't thought of as slang.

Comment: With many of nouns and verbs, you don't really need etymology to figure out whether the noun or the verb came first. I could *go for **a swim***, or ***stone** an adulteress* today (okay, the second is a bit iffy! :), but I'd bet any money ***swim*** was originally a verb, and ***stone*** was originally a noun. And when we *did* need to reference the first concept with a noun, or the second with a verb, why on earth would we bother inventing another new word?

Comment: @WS2: Aw contraire, I'd say such expressions are quite a delightful use of the language. Perhaps not to certain "refined" company, but in terms of actual linguistic cognition that is occurring - certainly.

Comment: @Claudiu I actually agree with WS2's main point that language—especially the English language—should be defended against unnecessary fuzziness. *Try and...*, for example, is easier to say but much less preferable semantically when compared with *try to...* That said, there's nothing unusual in *pajamas* going from a noun for a *thing* to a verb meaning *an act of using that thing*. English is littered with them.

Answer (score 2):

As @WS2 displayed in the comments above, your subjective experience isn't entirely mistaken. Middle English, trying to make sense of combining hordes of Germanic and French words into a single system, jettisoned a lot of the formatting that made the division between nouns and verbs clearer in Old English. Adding in a bunch of Latin forms with clean verb suffixes also covered up what was going on. You don't really think of *analyze* as a verbed noun, since it seems cleanly distinguished from *analysis*.

In fact, just like with Old English *gang* and *gong* and the backformation *analyze*, we've been nouning verbs and verbing nouns the entire time. WS2's complaint is against the ones he didn't learn while growing up. **The biggest shift w/r/t language in our time isn't that we've started doing this more**: it's that the old men who generally aim to tell everyone else how to talk (hint: like they learned at school) have much lower status in our society than 100 years ago, [leaving young girls freer rein to play around](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/teenage-girls-have-been-revolutionizing-language-16th-century-180956216/). [Analysis of 6000 period letters shows that even much of the linguistic playfulness and shifts attributed to Shakespeare actually appeared and became more fully adopted in the writing of young women of his age](https://qz.com/474671/move-over-shakespeare-teen-girls-are-the-real-language-disruptors/), the younger men of their age getting credit for it since they were the ones published and performed.

WS2 can break plenty of straightforward rules—starting sentences with conjunctions, adding commas at random, yoking together nouns and gerunds as if they were parallel concepts—and feel at ease scorning others' lack of affection for his mother tongue, because he's talking about modern-English-as-I-learned-it. The general disregard for [prescriptivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription) and the recognition of its [more-or-less-intentional effect of maintaining unwanted ethnic and class distinctions](https://harpers.org/wp-content/uploads/HarpersMagazine-2001-04-0070913.pdf) means you see less of this attitude at school, in publications, and online and the playfulness that was always there gets broadcast more.

Comment: This reads more like a criticism aimed at a single member, you mention him by name *three* times,   than the answer to the question *"Is this phenomenon indeed becoming more common/prevalent, particularly in North American English?"* remove the  tinged sarkiness and the answer is a good one.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel it unbecoming and undeserving of an upvote—particularly since, as you acknowledge, it is—but *I* wasn't the one accusing my fellows on and off this board of murder. It's fair to take that as the hyperbole it is; it is also fair to see that this is not a personal attack in the least but an immediate and completely apropos example of the type being described, which is essential to answering OP's question. If it makes you feel any better, the linked David Foster Wallace essay is actually a very spirited and warm-hearted defense of the other editor's point of view.

Comment: Mentioning someone by name three times, and implying that he is old fashioned, and old, (horrors)  reads like a  "personal attack". I used the term *criticism*, a softer word, so I think you made a [*Freudian slip*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Freudian%20slip) there :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm actually rather flattered that my three-line comment has generated such extensive analysis. Though I am still a little puzzled as to the main point being made. The way that any of us speak English is, I suppose, a reflection of who we are.